# Inline content inside li using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have header which has ul tag with content inside. I can't inline them.

HTML

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
      <div>
         <span><img src="1"></span>
         <p class="p1">row information</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
         <span><img src="1"></span>
         <p class="p1">row information</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
         <span><img src="1"></span>
         <p class="p1">row information</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftzLemjt/)

Comment: Are you trying to put the list items in a horizontal row?  If so, remove the flex-direction: column on the navbar-nav class.

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ftzLemjt/1/

Comment: @MichaelCoker almost like this, the last one what i'm trying is to align this content in one row, removing flex-direction: column helped, but it's native class of bootstrap is there any other ways?

Comment: do what @SeanGregory suggested and don't make that a flex `column` - that causes the children to stack vertically. The default for `display: flex` is a `row` so the elements are side by side https://jsfiddle.net/ftzLemjt/2/

Answer (score 1):

1) Delete all your CSS and include the bootstrap css and js from CDN since you are using the bootstrap navigation syntax.
2) Change the p element to a span and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

To inline them completely with images set *p1* class display style to *inline-block* and remove flex-direction. Like this:

```
.p1 {
  display: inline-block
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/toL6f4h5/